# Read XML and add it to a listView with multi columns

Tags: c#, xml, listview

how can i add subItems into my listView with 3 columns?
it only adds items to the first column

```
    //Read XML
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Xml.XmlDocument loadDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        loadDoc.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Computers.xml");

        foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode nameNode in loadDoc.SelectNodes("/Computers/Item"))
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(nameNode.Attributes["name"].InnerText); ;
        }

        foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode ipNode in loadDoc.SelectNodes("/Computers/Item"))
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(ipNode.Attributes["ip"].InnerText); ;
        }

        foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode macNode in loadDoc.SelectNodes("/Computers/Item"))
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(macNode.Attributes["mac"].InnerText); ;
        }


    }
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
 listView1.Items.Add(nameNode.Attributes["name"].InnerText); 
 listView1.Items[listview1.Items.Count-1].Subitems.Add(ipNode.Attributes["ip"].InnerText); 
 listView1.Items[listview1.Items.Count-1].Subitems.Add(macNode.Attributes["mac"].InnerText); ;
```